# Place something on top of a drop down (z-index doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, z-index

How can I place a html element (e.g. div or img) on top of a select with it's options using javascript, jquery and/or css? Z-index doesn't work in any browsers.

Comment: Did you try putting a position property on the element with z-index?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an iframe "shim" with a higher z-index. You can then put you element "on top" of that.

Answer (score 0):

another way would be to show/hide the drop-down whenever you hide/show the div/img or use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you use z-index and you want to layer one item on top of another without showing or hiding them, the best way will be to set absolute positioning on the top layer or possibly both DOM elements.

```
#item1, #item2{
position: absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
z-index:1;
}

#item2{
z-index:2;
}
```

Example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/UgrZz/2/)